# How to disable all buttons inside a TabControl

Tags: vb.net

I would really apreciate some help from the community, I am suffering programmer's block and have attempted to solve the issue in many ways, to no avail.

I created a demo (mockup) of a much larger project and have temporarily stored it here: 
[Demo of the issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zwkfj8zx62t1694/Demo.zip?dl=0)

*What is happening:*
If I press the `Exeggcute` button then buttons 1 thru 4 (In `TabPage1` and `TabPage2`) are disabled, and so are the `TabPage`s.

*What should happen:*
If I press the `Exeggcute` button then buttons 1 thru 4 (In `TabPage1` and `TabPage2`) should be changed to capital letters; however, this change should only affect the buttons and not the tabpages titles. The buttons are being disabled just as a proof of concept; the goal is to actually make their text all caps.

This is the code I am using:

`ctl.Text = UCase(ctl.Text)` - This does not work, why? I need the buttons to be shown in uppercase; however, only the option to disable them works. Why?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub BtnExeggcute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExeggcute.Click
        Dim ctl As Control
        For i = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
            ctl = Controls(i)
            If TypeOf ctl Is TabControl Then
                For j = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
                    If TypeOf Controls(j) Is TabControl Then
                        ctl.Text = UCase(ctl.Text) ' This does not work why? I need the buttons to be shown in uppercase; however, only disabling them works.
                        ctl.Enabled = False
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `If TypeOf Controls(j) Is TabControl Then` -- this doesn't allow your code to affect `Button`s

Comment: Iterate Buttons if you want to fiddle with Buttons .  It also easier to use `ofType` than all that `If TypeOf...` code

Comment: presumably your `j` loop should be looping over the `ctl.Controls` collection and not the form's `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on your existing approach, you need to go through each `TabControl`, then through each `TabPage`, and then through each `Button`.

You can use a `For Each` rather than a `For` if you're not doing anything with the index. You can also filter the control enumeration on each loop using [`Enumerable.OfType(Of TResult)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) rather than `TypeOf T Is` (as already mentioned by @plutonix).

```
' only controls which are TabControls
For Each tabControl As Control In Controls.OfType(Of TabControl)
    ' only controls in each TabControl which are TabPages
    For Each tabPage As Control In tabControl.Controls.OfType(Of TabPage)
        ' only controls in each TabPage which are Buttons
        For Each button As Control In tabPage.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
            ' reached a button! uppercase it's text
            button.Text = button.Text.ToUpperInvariant
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: @PatrickCool I rejected your edit which added `button.Enabled = False` - OP clearly stated that "_The buttons are being disabled just as a proof of concept; the goal is to actually make their text all caps._"

Comment: This is exactly right. @trashr0x , thank you for taking the time to teach the procedure step-by-step and commenting the code. Far too kind.

Comment: @vicsar glad I could help.